# Getting checkbox value in controller

Tags: django

I have a template that creates a text entry field and a checkbox. When the checkbox is unchecked, the text field is disabled and cleared, when it's checked, it's enabled, and the user may or may not have typed in it. In my controller I need to distinguish between the 2
cases when the checkbox is unchecked, and the checkbox is checked but the text field is blank. I can get the value of the text field, but not of the checkbox. Is there some way to do this? I've googled this, and I see it's been asked a few times here, but noneof the solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: Please show some code. Showing if a checkbox is checked is a fairly basic forms task.

Comment: Code would be nice. Also consider using the Django Debug Toolbar. If this is a jQuery (or other JS) related situation, Firebug is your friend.

Comment: Perhaps my question isn't clear. I am not having any problems creating the checkbox, nor getting its state in my jQuery code. I need to get its state back in my python controller.

Comment: No, your question is perfectly clear. It's impossible to answer it though, because you still haven't shown any code.

Comment: It's part of a very large, complex app. There's no simple, minimal example I can post.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.POST.get('my_checkbox_field')
```

P.S. In Django, they're called "views" not controllers.

**UPDATE (based on comment)**

I'm taking "controller" to mean "view" since Django doesn't have a concept of controllers and they're closest to views. If that's not the case, by all means correct me. Given that, all function-based views at the *very least* require a `request` parameter. If you're using class-based views, then `request` is simply stored on the view object, so you just need to modify it to `self.request`. I suggest you take some more time to thoroughly read the docs, as this is pretty much bare minimal understanding stuff that is well documented.

Comment: That gives me:*** NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: Isn't the view the template that causes the html to get rendered? And the controller is the python code that selects the data?

Comment: No, Django uses loose MVC, it has models, views, and templates. Views and templates are *close* to controllers and views, respectively, in MVC, but not exactly.

Comment: Yes, we are using class based views. self.request gives me: * AttributeError: 'MeasurementData' object has no attribute 'request'. I am clearly new to django, but I have read the docs. I've been very productive in a short time, but this is one thing I cannot figure out.

Comment: `MeasurementData` sounds like a model. Make sure your "view" is truly a subclass of `View` or one of its subclasses (`DetailView`, `ListView`, etc.)

Comment: Well, MeasurementData is not a model, but neither is it a view. It's a class that has methods that get called when the user clicks on a submit button. One of these methods is called generate_data, and that's what queries the db and returns data back to the template to be displayed. I'm working on a large, existing app, and I'm fairly new at the job. Unfortunately, there is no one here to ask - it was all done by one developer who is not here any more.

Comment: Ouch. Sounds like that developer did some pretty major customization. Post the code and maybe someone will be able to help you, but more than likely you're going to have to gut it and create a proper view.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
def myview(request):
    form = MyForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            checkbox = request.POST.get('my_checkbox', False) # will be True if checked

            if checkbox:
                # check textfield content
            else:
                # do something else

            return render_to_response(template, kwvars, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```